# Retrieving x, y coordinates from database

Tags: php, mysql, maps

I have a Server: Localhost via UNIX socket with a mySQL database which I access by using phpmyadmin. Now I got a table like this:
x double
y double
id smallint10 auto increment

The x and y values are used to store coordinates.
Now I want to get the newest coordinates from the database and show those in google maps.
So I would need a php script to get them. Then I would need a js script to show them in google maps.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a good question for Stackoverflow. You need to try something first and ask a more specific question if something does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try PHP + MySQL, which works great (PHP is a server side scripting service and MySQL is a database service, which works with PHP). You may go through **[PHP/MySQL Tutorial 1](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)** and **[PHP / MySQL Tutorial 2](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/)** to get an idea about how these things, like storing data into, and retrieving data from, MySQL database works, using PHP.

You may also have a look at **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/%E2%80%8E)**'s **[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** methods for retrieving data from a remote source, live, while staying on the same page, without navigating to another one. Here is a tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development/ (this may help you to show mysql results in google maps)

I recommend you to use PHP's **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)** method to do database operations, since the PHP manual itself says "Use of mysql extension is discouraged.". You may go through **[PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)**

Comment: Please don't encourage the usage of the mysql functions. The PHP manual itself says "Use of this extension is discouraged."

Comment: I know that. You may try PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `x`, `y` FROM `your_tables_name` WHERE `id` = 'id_number_of_coordinations'
```

... is about as simple as it gets. You'll need to look into querying mysql with PHP. I'd recommend using mysqli or PDO.